# identifier "operator + =" is not defined

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to implement the operator "+" with the help of delegation. But when I want to use the "+ =" operator, it cannot find it.

```
Money Money::operator +=(const Money &m)noexcept
{
    rouble += m.rouble;
    penny += m.penny;
    return *this;
}

Money operator + (const Money &first, const Money &second) noexcept
{
    return operator+=(second);
           ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can check.

Comment: The return statement needs to return to `first`;   it doesn't.    For example `return first.operator+=(second)`

Comment: Note that this problem has nothing to do with operator overloading. If you change `operator +=` to `my_func` everywhere you'll have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your second function (`operator+`) is free-standing, it is not a member. Your first function (`Money::operator+=`) *is* a member function; you can't just use the += member function as though it was free-standing.

So, in your second function, you probably want to do something like:

```
Money operator+ (const Money &first, const Money &second) noexcept
{
    Money sum{first}; 
    sum += second; 
    return sum; 
}
```

Having said that - you should also follow @πάνταῥεῖ's advice and read:

[What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)